# How to implement an interface and return certain type in TS?

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Inter{
    str:string
}

function func(){
    let v:Inter={
        str:'abc'
    };
    return v;
}
func()//how to make the type of value returned from `func` is {str:'abc'} not {str:string}
```

The return type of func is expected to `{str:'abc'}`, but I don't want to declare `{str:'abc'}` in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way:

```js
function func(){
    return {str: 'abc'} as const;
}
```